# Changing user settings in configuration prevents login on localhost

Tags: joomla3.8, configuration

In configuration.php, there is as user "root" and password "", when I put a password or modify something from there I cannot re-enter from local host.

I get the following error:

> Warning: session_start (): Failed to read session data: user (path: C: \ xampp \ tmp) in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ miweb \ libraries \ joomla \ session \ handler \ native.php on line 260
>
> Error: Failed to start application: Failed to start the session

[image]

Comment: Welcome to JSE, Martin.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for support from our volunteers.  They may have additional questions for you to respond to.

Answer (score 1):

Those are database connection settings. You must provide correct credentials otherwise your site won't work.

You shouldn't manually change these unless your site is already down due to incorrect credentials. If you want to change these settings for some other reason, you should do this through Global Configuration. This way database connection is validated before saving the settings.